# Not sure the current solution to my problem. Possibly looking to exclude sheet 1 in the script. But open to other solutions

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this spreadsheet I’m working on here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DQ4UMP4imUE0j5wHxFbnC0zVdCnfCXQRF9y9H3Lrxps/edit?usp=sharing

It currently has four sheets within it. I will be adding a sheet to it weekly. The first sheet is set up as a master or summary sheet that contains data (First and last Names) from every other sheet.

I’m running a script that currently tells all sheets to auto sort certain columns and ranges, upon entry in alphabetical order (the First and Last Names). Specifically these Columns: A, B, D, & E. The script itself is working great to accomplish the auto sorting.

What I am trying to do next is to get each sheet's first and last names to auto fill into the Summary Sheet (Sheet 1) so that I can have a master list (summary) of first and last names.

But here's where it get complicated and I run into issues. I would like the Summary sheet, Sheet 1, to not only auto sort the first and last names, in alphabetical order, just like the other sheets (which it does do currently) but I also need it to remove the duplicate names as they come in from different sheets.

The formula I have used in order to gather data from different sheets is currently set up as an array, and I have not been able to find a way to remove duplicates by using a UNIQUE function because it tells me it only looks for 1 argument but I have multiple data ranges coming in from all the different sheets.

I thought I could just simply manually "sort range" in the summary sheet, sheet 1, but due to the script I'm running that affects all sheets at the moment, if I try to select "sort range" on  the summary sheet, sheet 1, it doesn’t work properly.

I hope this makes sense, and Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Here is my current script.

```
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var columnToSortBy = 2;
    var tableRange = "A4:C102"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }

    var columnToSortBy = 5;
    var tableRange = "D4:F102"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }

    var columnToSortBy = 13;
    var tableRange = "L6:P19"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }

    var columnToSortBy = 9;
    var tableRange = "H25:P59"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }

    var columnToSortBy = 9;
    var tableRange = "H68:P102"; // What to sort.

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a reminder onEdit() script will timeout after 30 seconds.

Comment: Hello Josh, welcome to StackOverflow :-)
Your problem does not seem to lie in the `onEdit` function, that sorts your sheet, but rather in the function that imports the data from your sheets into the main sheet, since you want to filter for duplicates upon inserting the data, not upon sorting them. (eventhough you do this automatically together)
Therefore please replace your code with the code that imports your data and please also provide your approach to filter the duplicates, especially since it does not work.

Comment: As @PhilippMaurer said, please provide more info about the way you are filtering your main table, are you using a sheet formula or are you trying to do it with Apps Script?